# Where can I get the original images for the Accessory buttons in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, icons

I want to create a custom accessory icon to go to the right of my cell in a UITableView and want it to match the blue >, I have tried creating from scratch and it looks good on its own but when put next to a cell with the blue > it looks messy where the two icons look similar but not of the same style.  Does anyone know where I can get hold of the original DetailDisclosure button icon so I can use it as a base for my icon?  BTW tried doing a screen capture, but you don't get any transparency information with that.

Regards

Dave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this blog post:

http://0xced.blogspot.com/2009/04/extract-uikit-artwork.html

Put that code in a project and run it in the simulator.  It will extract the artwork from UIKit and save it in the app's Documents directory.  NSLog(documentsPath) to see where they're going.  It will save out tons of images for pretty much everything.